# updating value from mainwindow to dialog

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, qmainwindow

I have a mainwindow that generates random int numbers every second in "numbers" and I have a button that opens a new dialog. In that dialog is a button "Get Number" and a qlabel. If I press "Get Number" I want the current generated number from the mainwindow set to the dialog label text.  I tried to write a member function in the mainwindow class that returns the actual value but I cant call it from the dialog and I think that's the wrong way. How can I get this current generated int "numbers" into the dialog? My plain code:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void generateNumbers();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(generateNumbers()));
    timer->start(1000);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog dialog;
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.exec();
}

void MainWindow::generateNumbers()
{
    int numbers = qrand() % 100;
    qDebug() << numbers;
}
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Use signals and slots for that. In generateNumbers() emit a singnal numberGenerated(int). Connect that to a slot in the dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **mainwindow.h**, add a signal:

```
signals:
    void update_number(int);
```

On **mainwindow.cpp**, emit that signal everytime you generate a new number:

```
void MainWindow::generateNumbers()
{
    int numbers = qrand() % 100;
    emit update_number(numbers); // signals that a new number has been generated
    qDebug() << numbers;
}
```

and your `on_pushButton_clicked()` should look like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   Dialog dialog(this); // main window as the parent of dialog
   dialog.setModal(true);
   dialog.exec();
}
```

On **dialog.h**, add an attribute called `number_` and add the following slot:

```
public slots:
    void on_update_number(int number); // updates the number_

private:
    int number_; // it will be updated with the most recent number
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
```

On **dialog.cpp**, connect the signal to the slot:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(parent, SIGNAL(update_number(int)), this, SLOT(on_update_number(int)));
}
```

add the slot code:

```
void Dialog::on_update_number(int number)
{
    number_ = number;
}
```

Finally, when the user clicks the button "Get Number" in the dialog, set the label text:

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(number_));
}
```

For more information on Signals & Slots go [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: It works, thank you. I see no compiler errors but I get "QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_update_number(int)" at the application output. I already tried to emit and connect but I had no idea where to put connect in and how to talk to the mainwindow, you showed me with parent, thanx

Comment: I think I found the error. I changed the name to "when_update_number(int)". Error is gone.  "a slot named with on_ followed by the object name of a UI element followed by the name of a signal on that object will bet attempted to be connected automatically." Found here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65233-c-Qt5-Signals-and-slots